# how to prevent boot region when program the sam4e using jtag

Tags: arm, bootloader, iar

I am using at91sam4e16e and working on bootloader. boot region is defined at 0x400000 and application region is at 0x420000  onwards.

i have downloaded bootloader code into that region and compiled application code with 0x420000 link address. now I want to download that application to 0x420000 using Jtag but when I download it, all the memory goes erased and only application remains.

In avr, I could prevent the boot area in debugger option; How to do the same in sam4e?

regards,
shreyas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to project options.

In `Debugger -> Images` you can download extra image.

Note that I have only used this with the `Debug info only`-option enabled, but I have bundled bootloader with my app, so it is a bit different situation. (You can bundle bootloader in `Linker -> Input` tab.)

I also had a problem that since application wasn't in normal starting location, I had to initialize program counter, and stack pointer registers manually. You can do this by defining a macro file in `Debugger -> Setup`.

Macro file could look like this (note that this is for different MCU, so you may have different registers/addresses):

```
execUserReset() 
{
    // Set the stack pointer
    MSP = *(int*)0x00008000; 
    // Set the program counter
    PC = *(int*)0x00008004; 
}
```

This macro file skips bootloader when using debugger reset, but you could also make macro file which enters bootloader on reset by using different addresses.

**Edit:** Bundling the bootloader:

It's been a while since I have done this, so hopefully I remember everything.

You need to add your bootloader `.bin` file to `Linker -> Input -> Raw binary image`. Also define symbol `bootloader`, and section `.bootloader`. (I think alignment needs to be specified too, even if you use absolute placement.)

Add your `bootloader` symbol to `Keep symbols:` box above. This should make sure that bootloader is always included.

In your linker file, add line

```
place at address mem:0x00000000 { section .bootloader };
```

to place bootloader at specific address (change address to match your bootloader address).

Comment: I was able to change the start location using debugger -> setup macros. but using linker -> input was not making any difference to the binary generated. Why so?